# How to move words in a row to the next one and add indentation if there are more than x words?

Tags: bash

I have a file that acts like a logbook and have a few long lines, when opening it looks like that:

```
DATE        DAY   ACTIVITY
00/11/22    Fri   - aaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbb
01/11/22    Sat   - kjbckjassakkja
```

I would like it to look like:

```
DATE        DAY   ACTIVITY
00/11/22    Fri   - aaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbb
                    bbbbb
01/11/22    Sat   - kjbckjassakkja
```

Thanks

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Are there spaces or tabs?

Comment: Yeah, looks so neat you probably invested a lot of time and effort already trying to get this done?

Comment: I struggled with this one and couldn't come up with anything useful to share, was hoping that the description will be enough. But yes, this is more for the final touches of a rather long script. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the title, I assume the "bbbbb" line continues from the
previous line without a linebreak, but it looks like folded due to the width
of the terminal.
As the question is tagged with `bash`, how about:

```
#!/bin/bash

limit=39                                # fold the line at the 39th character
while IFS= read -r line; do             # read each line 
    if (( ${#line} > limit )); then     # the line length exceeds the limit
        s=${line%-*}                    # extract the substring before "-"
        len=$(( ${#s} + 2 ))            # length to indent
        echo "${line:0:limit}"          # print the 1st half
        printf "%${len}s%s\n" " " "${line:limit}"
                                        # print the remaining with indentation
    else
        echo "$line"                    # shorter lines are not affected
    fi 
done < file
```

Input file:

```
DATE        DAY   ACTIVITY
00/11/22    Fri   - aaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
01/11/22    Sat   - kjbckjassakkja
```

Output:

```
DATE        DAY   ACTIVITY
00/11/22    Fri   - aaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbb
                    bbbbb
01/11/22    Sat   - kjbckjassakkja
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe '
    $l = 2 + index $_, "-" if /-/;
    print " " x $l unless 2 == index $_, "/";
' file
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints each line after running the code
- `$_` contains the current line
- [index](http://p3rl.org/index) returns the position of `-` in the current line, but only if the current line matches `/-/`, i.e. it contains any dash
- `$l` will hold the indentation length, it's the position of the dash plus 2
- `x` is the repetition operator
- if the third character is not a `/`, print `$l` spaces before printing the line.